# How to call an overloaded operator from a nested class inside parent in a header file?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, header-files, inner-classes

I have an enum class `E` nested in class `C`. I want to use it as bit flags, so I overloaded its operators.

My class `C` contains function `test()` which makes use of overloaded operators. Because it is only two lines long, it is located in the header file to be inlined. However, this function does not call the overloaded operator, and instead uses the default one.

I understand that it may be because my operators are defined after class `C`, so `C` does not know that they exist. I could move the nested enum outside and define the operators before class `C`, but I am wondering, is there a way to do it while preserving `C::E` hierarchy?

**main.cpp**

```
#include "myenum.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << "Should be false (main): " << ((C::E::e2 | C::E::e4) != C::E::e4) << std::endl;
    C c(C::E::e2 | C::E::e4);
    c.test(C::E::e4);
    return 0;
}
```

**myenum.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

class C {
public:
    enum class E {
        e2 = 2,
        e4 = 4
    };

    const E e;

    C(E e) : e(e) {}

    void test(E e) {
        std::cout << "Should be false (test): " << (this->e != e) << std::endl;
    }
};

// Flag active
inline bool operator==(C::E lhs, C::E rhs) {
    auto l = static_cast<std::underlying_type<C::E>::type>(lhs);
    auto r = static_cast<std::underlying_type<C::E>::type>(rhs);
    auto value = l & r;
    return value == r || value == l;
}

// Flag inactive
inline bool operator!=(C::E lhs, C::E rhs) {
    std::cout << "Overloaded operator call" << std::endl;
    return !(lhs == rhs);
}

inline C::E operator|(C::E lhs, C::E rhs) {
    return (C::E)(static_cast<std::underlying_type<C::E>::type>(lhs) | static_cast<std::underlying_type<C::E>::type>(rhs));
}
```

Comment: You have to implement `test` after custom operator overloadings. Or maybe you can use a template to define operators later

Comment: @김선달 This is actually a good idea. I didn't know that it is allowed to have implementation and declaration separate but both in header files. I am not sure about templates though, how they could be used?

Comment: It is allowed if the `test` is an `inline` function. More precisely, there can be a duplication error if the function is not `inline` when `myenum.h` was included in more than 1 files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class C {
public:
    enum class E {
        e2 = 2,
        e4 = 4
    };

    const E e;

    C(E e) : e(e) {}

    inline void test(E e); // function must be inline
};

// Flag active
inline bool operator==(C::E lhs, C::E rhs) ...


// implement later
inline void C::test(C::E e) {
  // do stuff
}
```

I can't think of templates that work for your version.
Maybe this will be the best.